# Javascript regex, splitting on newline and colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a string by `:` and by `\n`. I am not sure as to why the line of code below does not work.

```
let contents = response.split("[:\n]");
```

Comment: You should use a regex - `response.split(/[:\n]/)`

Comment: I thought the line of code above is a regex.

Comment: Only if you read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)...

Comment: Note the use of wrapping `//` vs `""`

Comment: It's just your syntax that's off. Play around with it on this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to put the expression in quotes. Guess that only applies when splitting on a single character?

Comment: You can use a string here -- you are just using the wrong one. This works fine for colon AND new line: `response.split(":\n")`

Comment: @user3131097 No, `""` is how you build a string, `//` is how you build a regex in JavaScript. (Though some functions will try to cast a string parameter to a regex, yeah ok it's not always clear...)

Comment: Guys like @WiktorStribiżew who don't even care about the rep and just put the answer in the comments always impress me.

Comment: @JosephCho The question is an evident dupe/typo question. It should be removed.

Comment: @user3131097 When you provide a string to `split` it will litterally look for that string and use it as a separator. If you want a regex you should provide a regex using: **1.** regex literal: `.split(/.../)` or **2.** a regex object: `.split(new RegExp("..."))`.

Comment: This splits on a `:` or a `\n`.  `response.split(/[:\n]/) ` If you want `:` AND `\n` you don't need the brackets: `response.split(/:\n/)`

Comment: Because he knows well about banal question which is gonna be closed. @JosephCho